# how access the user control Active X in web page using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed user control for ActiveX control in C# then register this component & access as ActiveX control from access . I want to access this user control in internet explorer .
how to access Active X control as web page?

i have developed the windows application & registered the ActiveX control at the time of installation of this application through setup (.NET) .i want to access this user control in the internet explorer page so i want to stored this user control web page at the time of installation permanently .
 how to stored this web page of access the registered  active X control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the "[object](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp)" tag

```
<object id="myComObject" 
        classid="clsid:8B4DB064-FD61-11D5-9E82-00D059119277"></object>
<script>
    myComObject.DoStuff();
</script>
```

Comment: i already try this code but there is no display in the web page this code work in html not in ASP.net. the clsid code is same for all computer or different

Comment: This is not an ASP.NET issue - it's a HTML issue. Please edit your question to show any existing code and I'll try to diagnose your issue.

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx can you please refer this link check the attach file because same thing i want but it will not display any thing in the website but in the article  it display the right o/p .please check

Comment: Yes, but what's your existing code - I can't tell why it's not working unless you show what you've done...

Comment: I am not change any code from the following link. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx 
Please check the attached application. When I run the application it not display any controls on screen. They change some properties, but I don’t get these properties.
I want to run my windows control on web page using asp.net.